# Extrude in curves

Tags: bezier-curves

Inside Curve Properties there's a Extrude option that creates faces along a curve. When use free handles to make a sharp angle the faces around the free handles have ununified shape like shown below. I find the same problem in Solidify modifier that with Even Thickness off the shape around the sharp angle looks bad and with Even Thickness on it looks good. It's because without even thickness each vertex will extrude the same distance whereas sometimes some vertex(for instance the vertex that forms a sharp angle) needs to extrude longer to make the overall shape unified. So is there a way to achieve the same result for curves like even thickness in Solidify?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is blender limitation, but there is another way to achive that
you can extrude in curve property as thin as possible,
[image]

then add Solidify modifier and check even thickness, you may add Weld modifier to keep one side surface in case you dont need double sided (solidified surface),
[image]

Here the result
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm, in my case I need to set the curve points 90 degrees tilt. The only pity is that the Bevel-Depth of curve properties no longer works correctly with it since the curve has a Solidify modifier. But it's already very good, thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, if i understand you may add solidify again after weld modifier and then add bevel modifier i think it will get similar result.
also, if this answer you looking for, please consider to mark answer accepted

Comment: Yes, with a bevel modifier it would have similar result and thank you again for your kind help